# using caffemodels in matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network, caffe

This is my first time trying to use caffemodels in matlab so I am a bit lost - I have downloaded a caffemodel (CNN) from this website: https://data.vision.ee.ethz.ch/cvl/rrothe/imdb-wiki/, and I am now simply trying to use it to make an estimation of age for an image. So far my attempt looks like this:

```
net = importCaffeNetwork('prot.prototxt', 'dex_imdb_wiki.caffemodel');

%% read image
image2 = imread('image2.jpg');
image2 = imresize(im2double(image2),[224 224]);

net(image2)
```

net is a CNN with 41 layers, where it in the first layer has an input of size [224 224 3]. When I run "net(image2)" I get the error "Array indices must be positive integers or logical values".

And I simply can't figure out how to fix this problem..

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: I think you need this: `classify(net,image2);`

Comment: ooh yeah - now I am at least getting a result - but I get ypred = class22 no matter what image i input :( I am guessing that it might have something to do with this "For age estimation the output layer has 101 neurons (0-100 years, one for each year). To obtain the predicted age, you need to take the expected value over the softmax-normalized output probabilities" - but it still doesn't really make sense to me that they all should start as class22 - and I don't quite understand what it is that they are telling me to do

Comment: Have you tried with an image about which you're sure that will give something other than `class22`?

Comment: yes, I tried with images of really old people and kids

Comment: Why are you using `im2double` btw?

Comment: omg, that was it - thank you so much! :D I don't quite remember why I did that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`classify`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/classify.html) from the NN Toolbox is what you're looking for. 
For some reason, your caffe model doesn't work with images of double class. So overall the following is what you need:

```
net = importCaffeNetwork('prot.prototxt', 'dex_imdb_wiki.caffemodel');
image2 = imread('image2.jpg');
image2 = imresize(image2, [224 224]);
age_pred = classify(net, image2);
```